# How can I include custom SELECTs in my queries

Tags: javascript, prisma

For a blog website I am currently making I need to retrieve the recent articles from the database to show them on the main page of the blog. I do not want to retrieve the content of all 10 last articles but rather the beginning of them.

In Postgres, I would find all the articles, sort them by a `created_at` field, and `SELECT` the content with `SELECT left(content, 15)` to get the 15 first characters of the content of my article.

How can I achieve this with Prisma?

I tried

```js
  return prisma.article.findMany({
    orderBy: {
      createdAt: 'desc',
    },
    select: {
      createdAt: true,
      id: true,
      title: true,
      updatedAt: true,
      content: 'left(content, 15)' as any
    },
  });
```

But it tells me that it is expecting a boolean value instead of string.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You could do what Ryan suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68456866/5996699) (the second suggestion being that you introduce a new field, maybe something like `excerpt`) OR you could do a [raw query](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/raw-database-access) like so:

```js
import { Article } from '@prisma/client';

type CustomArticle = Pick<Article, 'id' | 'title' | 'content' | 'createdAt' | 'updatedAt'>;

const prisma = /* your prisma client */
const result = await prisma.$queryRaw<CustomArticle[]>`SELECT id, title, LEFT(content, 15) as content, createdAt, updatedAt FROM Article;`
```

You can do this but **I suggest you introduce a new field instead** as `LEFT(content, 15)` will still fetch the whole content but strip everything after the 15th character.

> In this example I used TypeScript to determine `$queryRaw`s generic type parameter `T` with a `CustomArticle` which picks only the relevant information we need so we can have a typed return value.

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not directly possible with Prisma, so there are two workarounds to this:

1. Fetch the content and then just display the first 15 characters on the frontend.
2. Create another field that just holds the first 15 characters of `content` and select that field.

We have a request for this [here](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/7039) so it would be great if you could add a  to this so that we can look at the priority.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'll leave this open for now waiting for a viable solution